# I need to obtain max and min from datatable

Tags: mysql

I have a database with Name (aseguradora), Price (Precact) and Date (Ultdato). $matriu1 is a variable (table from datatable). Id is a variable (date selection from user)

I want to select the max and min price and date from both to show it, but the date not show the correct date. I think that I need to create a subquery, but I'm not sure. Any help? THANKS!

```
$sqle= "SELECT MIN(Precact), Ultdato 
FROM $matriu1[3] 
WHERE Aseguradora = '$aseguradora' AND Id <= '$fecha'"; // Seleccionem el valor mínim

$sqlf= "SELECT * MAX(Precact), Ultdato 
FROM $matriu1[3] 
WHERE Aseguradora = '$aseguradora' AND Id <= '$fecha'"; // Seleccionem el valor màxim
```

Comment: this code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection**, so please use only **prepared statemenst with parameters** see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use next approach:

```
SELECT Precact, Ultdato 
FROM $matriu1[3]
JOIN (
    MIN(Precact) minPrecact FROM $matriu1[3]
    WHERE
        Aseguradora = '$aseguradora' AND
        Id <= '$fecha'
) minPrecact ON minPrecact = Precact
```

Comment: Sorry for my late answer and thanks so much for your help.